# Unable to add,commit or push local file to bitbucket repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have 3 branches (branchone, branchtwo & branchthree) apart from the master branch in my bitbucket repository called "test".

I cloned the repo on my local Windows and got the README.md file.

I then created Jenkinsfile did add, commit & push. I can see the Jenkins file on bitbucket master branch.

I then switched to branchone using "git checkout branchone" and verified the same using git branch command

```
F:\Jenkins\MultiBranch\test>git branch
* branchone
  master
  branchtwo
  branchthree
```

I confirmed I had Jenkinsfile and then "git add ." or "git add Jenkinsfile" but git status shows nothing is staged

```
F:\Jenkins\MultiBranch\test>git status
```

> On branch branchone
> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/branchone'.
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

Below are my questions:

1. Why does git not add the Jenkinsfile to branchone when i was able to add it to master branch ?
2. Is there a way I can push the Jenkinsfile to all the Branches in one go ?
3. Is it possible to create sub-branches under branchone ? like branch1.1 & branch1.2 etc from the bitbucket console ? If it is not possible from console is it possible by other means ?

Answer (score 1):

1.When you added your jenkins file to master, committed it and checked out branchone, the jenkins file would not have been there as you already have committed it to master. 
Hence, even if you do `git add .`, there won't be anything to add in branchone. If you specifically create jenkins file again in your branch one, then you will be able to add it to branchone and commit.

2.I'm not sure how you can simultaneously apply changes to multiple branches in one go. However, You can do so individually for each branch in following ways :

- Add it manually to each branch and commit
- Cherry pick master's commit including jenkins file and apply it on all branches individually
- Merge/rebase all branches individually with master

3.There is no concept of sub branches in git. You just have a branch. Branch is just a pointer to a commit. When you say you have branchone, branchone is pointer to commit with #abc123. This commit may have its own tree of commits before it.

When you delete a branch, the pointer to the commit is deleted and not the commit itself. Now, coming back to your question, you can create any number of branches starting from a branch. You can use the command `git checkout -b newBranchName`.

If you create a new branch from branchone, Both branchone and newbranch will point to the same commit earlier pointed by branchone. If you add another commit in new branch, only newbranch pointer will move up to point to the latest commit and branchone pointer will stay at the original commit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. Remains unanswered because I have explicitly created a Jenkinsfile locally and made sure it is there before adding it to branchone

Comment: Then you should have seen it in git status and you would have been able to add it with git add unless your .gitignore file contains a match for jenkins file.

Comment: F:\Jenkins\MultiBranch\test>dir
 Volume in drive F is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 3898-EFD1

 Directory of F:\Jenkins\MultiBranch\test

 17-05-2019  11:00    <DIR>          .
17-05-2019  11:00    <DIR>          Jenkinsfile
17-05-2019  10:53               593 README.md


    F:\Jenkins\MultiBranch\test>git add Jenkinsfile

    F:\Jenkins\MultiBranch\test>git status
On branch branchone
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/branchone'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: No ... git status does not show any changes and thats the problem i am reporting.

Comment: This is strange. If the filename does not match with any query in .gitignore file and  if you have made changes to the file, it should show in git status.

Comment: The issue is resolved. The problem was Jenkinsfile was created as a directory instead of a file is why it was not working. Once it was recreated as a file everything  started to work with the shared command.

Comment: Now it makes sense why it was not showing in git status. Git does not track empty directories.